# How do I increase the size of the black space, so I have more room to reposition these two clips?

Tags: premiere-pro

I imported two clips into premiere pro, one is some dashcam footage, and the other is the screen recorded off my phone, where the screen shows a map.  (I got premiere pro to synchronise them by audio)  So regarding the two clips, we have the dashcam clip, and the phone screen clip.

I'd like to make both big and side by side..  Or make the dashcam one big and the screen one in the corner. I know there are options to position and scale, in effect controls.

But what I can do seems very limited, because I can only work within the black area, and the black area(within the program window) is so small. I need that black area to be much bigger, much wider, to give me room to put the two clips side by side or to experiment with how I position the two clips.

How can I widen that black area in the program window?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new sequence with the dimensions you need by clicking on File —> New —> Sequence. Common sizes for HD video are 1920x1080 pixels or 3840x2160 for 4K.

Then drag your footage into this sequence. If you need to adjust the size, make sure your clip is selected in the sequence, then go to Effects Settings and adjust the Scale under the Motion settings.

Might be an idea to follow through all of the steps in this tutorial to get the hang of it first:

https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/creating-changing-sequences.html